# How can i get the value from div class in TestNG selenium?

Tags: selenium

I am using TestNG and selenium for testing web app.

```
<div class="infoMessage">The request has been successfully submitted.</div>
```

In the my TestNG class file, like any other HTML elments for div element also
I have

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='wrapper']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div")
WebElement resultdiv;
```

Now that I got the webelement in resultdiv, how can i read the content "The request has been successfully submitted" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @bnath002 You can use **Contains text Xpath**, below is the code. this code always work for text.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'The request has been successfully submitted.')]"));
String innerText= element.getText();
System.out.println("Your inner text is: "+innerText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just at a quick glance, it seem like you can try use `className` instead `xpath`:

```
@FindBy(className="infoMessage")
WebElement resultdiv;
```

Use `.getText();` to achieve:

```
String text = resultdiv.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unfamiliar with @FindBy, but i'm assuming you could use getText() as normal. But if everything went as planned and the xpath located your element successfully, you should be able to retrieve the text with the following :)

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div"));
String innerText= element.getText();
System.out.println("Your inner text is: "+innerText);
```